# How to inherit only few fields in odoo 12 model

Tags: python, model, odoo

I can't figure out how I inherit only one or few selective fields for eg:
**my.model.main** ---> **my.model.test**
if model **my.model.main** has columns *[a,b,c,d,e,f,g]* , I want only to inherit columns *[a,d,g]* in the new model **my.model.test**
Please share a sample code for odoo 12
Thank you :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't inherit if you can only make use of a few columns of the base model. A cleaner approach in this is case is to separate the columns [a, d, g] into a separate model **my.model.mixin** and then let **my.model.test** and **my.model.main** both inherit from **my.model.mixin**.

If you still want to only inherit a few columns, you'd need to look into the functions **init_models**, **_auto_init**, and **init**. The **init** method can be overridden to implement your own custom database scheme for your model. This is usually only recommended for adding some indices or defining a view though and will probably lead to more problems if you remove columns in there.